# Find current and VAB with Superposition Theorem

Tags: voltage, current, superposition

Struggling to solve the following circuit with superposition theorem...

[image]

I know I need to examine the circuit with each battery in isolation but I am confused how to treat all the resistors as they are all in parallel. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: If you eliminate (short) two of the sources, the resistors will not **all** be in parallel.

Comment: Note: the resistors are **not** in parallel (they'd be in parallel if also the bottom terminals of the resistors were connected to one common node)

Comment: Can you explain a little more please? If I replace V2 and V3 with links the circuit still looks the same. I have struggled with this previously, would R2 be in series?

Comment: A super-position is: \$\frac{V_A}{R_1}+\frac{V_A}{R_2}+\frac{V_A}{R_3}=\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_2}{R_2}+\frac{V_3}{R_3}\$. (That's current spilling outward superimposed on current spilling inward, in a sense.) Then \$V_A=\left( \frac{V_1}{R_1}+ \frac{V_2}{R_2} + \frac{V_3}{R_3} \right) \cdot \left( R_1\mid\mid R_2\mid\mid R_3 \right)\$, treating \$V_B\$ as the reference point. In that sense, all three resistors are in parallel.

Comment: Two elements are in parallel only if both of their terminals are connected together. So that exactly the same potential appears across the two elements. Looking at the original circuit, **none** of the resistors are in parallel, because the lower terminal of each one is connected to a different node, at a different potential from the lower terminals of the other resistors.

Comment: When you start shorting out some sources to do part of a superposition solution, you might find that some of the resistors are then in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Although it can be solved using superposition I think it's much easier to use Thevenin/Norton equivalents:

What you have are 3 Thevenin sources in parallel (i.e. voltage sources that have a resistor connected in series).

A Thevenin source can easily be transformed into an equivalent Norton source (i.e. a current source that has a resistor connected in parallel):
\$R_{Norton}=R_{Thevenin}\$ and \$I_{Norton}=\frac{V_{Thevenin}}{R_{Thevein}}\$

Do this for each of the 3 Thevenin sources and you get 3 Norton sources in parallel, i.e. you get 3 current sources and 3 resistors connected in parallel.

3 current sources in parallel can be replaced by 1 current source whose current value is the sum of the 3 single sources: \$I_{tot}=I_1+I_2+I_3\$

3 resistors in parallel can be replaced by one resistor whose resistance value 
is also easily computed: \$\frac{1}{R_{tot}}=\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_3}\$.

Comment: I can't answer with Norton I need to use superposition theorem. I just can't rearrange the circuit at all.